# How to manipulate JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

**I am using angular.js with asp.net mvc 4. I am trying to pass jason data through ajax request to an action of my controller.
Here is  my script:**

```
$scope.items = [
   { Name: "Name1", Email: "Email1", Address: "Address1", ContactNo: "contactNo1"},
   { Name: "Name2", Email: "Email2", Address: "Address2", ContactNo: "contactNo1"}
];

var users = JSON.stringify($scope.items);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Angular/saveData",
            data: users,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

**I can't figure out what will be my "saveData" action to manupulate the jason data?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult saveData(DataClass[] items)
  {

  }
```

The data class:

```
public class DataClass {
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Email {get; set; }
    public string Address {get; set; }
    public string ContactNo {get; set; }
}
```